# Responsive doesnt work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the meta tag below in all my pages (these pages are in an iframe) but I don't know why it doesn't work. I used bootstrap 3 to make all the pages responsive.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

someone can help me please?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```